# How to pull a repo by other, after rename the branch name in git?

Tags: git, repository

I have 2 branches in my repo. `master` and `dev`. I want to rename `dev` to `old-dev` and create a new `dev`.

I renamed `dev` to `old-dev` in my local and origin by these codes:

```
git branch -m dev old-dev
git push origin --delete dev
git branch --unset-upstream old-dev
git push origin old-dev
git push origin -u old-dev
```

then I create a new `dev` branch. Now I have `master`, `old-dev` and `dev` in the origin.

But other teammates have `master` and `dev` (This `dev` is the same `old-dev`)

What do they need to do to sync with this process? If they just pull, all the branches will be correct?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. They should delete `dev` first and then `pull`

```
git branch -D dev
git pull --all
```

Comment: Rule 1: Don't use `--all` with `git pull`. (Rule 0: Don't use `git pull`, but if you must violate rule zero, see rule 1. ) The reason is that `git pull` passes `--all` to `git fetch`, where it means *all repositories*. This makes some sense in `git fetch`, but none in `git pull`.

Comment: Other than that, this is a reasonable thing to do—but they should note that if they have their own work *on* their `dev` branches, they should probably save that work by renaming their own `dev` branches, e.g., `git branch -m dev save`. After that they don't need to do anything special: running `git fetch` or `git pull` will Just Work.